# How to send search request to elastic by ElasticsearchRestTemplate with terminate_after param?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I do request to elastic cluster for Document entity using ElasticsearchRestTemplate. My DAO class:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.aggregation.AggregatedPage;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.SearchQuery;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import APP_PACKAGE.dto.request.DocElasticFilterDto;
import APP_PACKAGE.dto.request.DocElasticPaginationDto;
import APP_PACKAGE.model.entity.Document;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DocumentDao {
    private final ElasticsearchRestTemplate esTemplate;

    @NotNull
    public AggregatedPage search(@NotNull DocElasticFilterDto filter, @NotNull DocElasticPaginationDto pagination) {
        SearchQuery query = DocumentQueryBuilderKt.buildSearchQuery(filter, pagination);
        return esTemplate.queryForPage(query, Document.class);
    }
}
```

ElasticsearchRestTemplate send to elastic this http request:

```
curl -iX POST 'http://HOST:9200/INDEX/_doc/_search?rest_total_hits_as_int=true&typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512' -d '{"from":0,"size":1,"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"terms":{"pgs":[2],"boost":1.0}},{"terms":{"t":[2],"boost":1.0}}],"adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1.0}},"version":true,"sort":[{"t":{"order":"desc"}}]}'
```

I want send request with [terminate_after](http://terminate_after) (compute for each search like `from` + `size` (params from pagination DTO)) param like this:

```
curl -iX POST 'http://HOST:9200/INDEX/_doc/_search?rest_total_hits_as_int=true&typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512&terminate_after=1' -d '{"from":0,"size":1,"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"terms":{"pgs":[2],"boost":1.0}},{"terms":{"t":[2],"boost":1.0}}],"adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1.0}},"version":true,"sort":[{"t":{"order":"desc"}}]}'
```

How can i do this with spring-data-elasticsearch?

---

I found possible solution - using RestHighLevelClient without spring data library

```
    fun search(filter: DocElasticFilterDto, pagination: DocElasticPaginationDto): DocElasticSearchResult<DocElasticDto> {
        val query = buildSearchQuery(filter)
        log.debug("#search: query: $query")
        val searchSourceBuilder = buildSourceBuilder(query)
        searchSourceBuilder.size(pagination.limit)
        val from = pagination.page * pagination.limit
        searchSourceBuilder.from(from)
        searchSourceBuilder.terminateAfter(from + pagination.limit)

        val response = esClient.search(buildRequest(searchSourceBuilder), RequestOptions.DEFAULT)

        return DocElasticSearchResult(getResults(response), response.hits.totalHits!!.value)
    }

    private fun buildRequest(searchSourceBuilder: SearchSourceBuilder) :SearchRequest {
        val searchRequest = SearchRequest(indexName)
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder)
        return searchRequest
    }

    private fun buildSourceBuilder(queryBuilder: QueryBuilder) :SearchSourceBuilder {
        val searchSourceBuilder = SearchSourceBuilder()
        searchSourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder)
        searchSourceBuilder.timeout(TimeValue.parseTimeValue(readTimeout, "timeout"))
        return searchSourceBuilder
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `terminate_after` parameter is currently not supported in Spring Data Elasticsearch.